# For which $n$ is the $n$-dimensional hypercube a planar graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

I've been asked the following question:
For which values of $n$ is $Q_n$ a planar graph, where $Q_n$ is the $n$-dimensional hypercube?
I succeeded to prove that for $n$ equal or greater than $6$ it won't be, but I know that actually $Q_n$ is a planar graph if and only if $n \leq 3$.
Please help 
Thx

Comment: Yes- it's a planar graph(sorry) and Qn is hypercube with n vertices.

Comment: [Related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/859394/3736).

Comment: thanks mate it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[$K_{3,3}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_utilities_problem) is a [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) of $Q_4$, hence $Q_4$ is not a planar graph, and obviously $Q_4$ is a minor of $Q_n$ for any $n>4$, hence the only planar hypercubes are $Q_n$ with $n\leq 3$.

[image]

Another approach: $Q_4$ is a triangle-free graph, but any planar and triangle-free graph with $n$ vertices has at most $2n-4$ edges. $Q_4$ has $16$ vertices and $32>2\cdot 16-4$ edges, so $Q_4$ cannot be a planar graph.

Another approach may be to compute the [Colin de Verdière graph invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin_de_Verdi%C3%A8re_graph_invariant), since the [spectrum of the adjacency matrix of $Q_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph) has a nice, easily-provable structure.

Comment: I liked the simple approach of the first one, but i'm not sure how to formally prove it, I asumming that you cant consider a painted graph as a formal prove.

Comment: @RoeyWaitsman: a depicted embedding is a formal proof that an embedding exists, what is the issue with that?

Comment: @RoeyWaitsman, if you can show that K3,3 is a minor of Q4 then you're done.

Comment: @RoeyWaitsman: I added a picture showing the embedding: $A,B,C$ are sources, $a,b,c$ are wells and I hope the dijoint paths $Xy$ for $X\in\{A,B,C\}$ and $y\in\{a,b,c\}$ are clearly depicted.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio , thank you for depicting it, its clearly understood now.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Is there another way of proving that $Q_4$ is a nonplanar graph??Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

$K_5$ is a minor of $Q_4$. You can show this in the following "inductive" way. Here I assume that vertices of the cube $Q_n$ are represented by 0-1 strings of length $n$, and edges are put between two vertices that differ in exactly one coordinate.

$K_3$ is a minor of $Q_2$. This is true because in $Q_2$ we can contract $\{00,01\}$ edge to get $K_3$.

$K_4$ is a minor of $Q_3$. To prove this consider $Q_3(0)$ and $Q_3(1)$ to be subgraphs of $Q_3$ induced on set of vertices of form $0xy$ and $1xy$ respectively. Note that both $Q_3(0)$ and $Q_3(1)$ are isomorphic to $Q_2$. Now we contract all vertices in $Q_{3}(1)$ into a single vertex $n$ (which is adjacent to everyone in $Q_{3}(0)$) and on $Q_{3}(0)$ we contract the vertices to produce $K_3$. After those two contraction we get a $K_4$ minor in $Q_3$.

Similarly, $K_5$ is a minor of $Q_4$. Consider $Q_4(0)$ and $Q_4(1)$ to be subgraphs of $Q_3$ induced on set of vertices of form $0xyz$ and $1xyz$ respectively. Contract all vertices in $Q_{4}(1)$ into a single vertex $n$ (which is adjacent to everyone in $Q_{4}(0)$) and on $Q_{4}(0)$ we contract the vertices to produce $K_4$. After those two contraction we get a $K_5$ minor in $Q_4$.

By induction, I think, you can prove that for all $n\geq 0$ the hypercube $Q_n$ contains $K_{n+1}$ as a minor (case $n=0,1$ actually give you a subgraph which is stronger than a minor). So for $n\geq 4$, $Q_{n}$ has $K_5$ as a minor and therefore is not planar ([Wagner theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%27s_theorem)).

This approach uses Wagner criterion of planarity (forbidden minors). There is a solution based on Kuratowski's criterion, $Q_4$ case is considered on the wiki page on [planar graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph).